# Sticky candy apples

Tags: candy

Last night I made candy apples for the second time. The first time they were perfect. Last night I made them at 10 pm and let them sit out over night. This morning they were hard but still sticky.

The only difference with the first batch is the sugar I used, this time it was super fine. The humidity in my house was at 60%. Was it the sugar I used?

Comment: We can't compare with the humidity the first time.

Comment: Was the superfine sugar the first batch, or the recent one?  Also, are you using a candy thermometer?  (if you don't get it to the right temperature, it can end up sticky, even if you have low humidity)